# Jquery delete row is getting wrong row ID

Tags: jquery

I am trying to delete row, but it always gives me the ID of the previous row:
this is my code:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")) {

                if ($('.TDpackID').children().val() != 0)
                {
                    deletedPacksIDS.push($('.TDpackID').children().val());
                }

                $(this).closest('tr').remove();

            }
```

and there are the rows:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uUY9.png)

I am trying to delete id: "101" but the value of the id is "100" which is the previous row

here is my table: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeyNY.png)

Comment: `$('.TDpackID').children().val() != 0)
                {` will obviously retrun first childs value. Because your `td` has 2 children, and `val()` will get the value of first. Also *both elements have same ID*. I am not sure what you're trying to do as both inputs are hidden

Comment: so how to get the selected child value ?

Comment: they are hidden because they are the same tag, I am trying to get the ID of the current row

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a class to each of your input first,then you can get hold of the click event like

```
$(".inputCls").click(function(){      
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Or use event delegation in case you are generating rows dynamically

```
$(document).on('click','.inputCls', function() {
   //do the operaton here
});
```

On reading your question further and looking at your html I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do.

If you are looking to remove the input with value 100 under the td then you can do it by creating a function like this

```
function removeInputElement(value){    
    $('.TDpackID').children().find("input[value='"+value+"']").remove();    
}
```

call it then with desired value

```
removeInputElement(100);
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: no, I still have the same problem of getting the previous ID

Comment: The delete function deletes an entire row, so the ID and value are not static see the edit, I added an image

Comment: What exactly is the problem?please edit your question with clear description.it looks like a very simple thing,but your unability to communicate things out clearly isn't helping.